# RESideMenu-Two Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I'm using this for a side menu in my app: https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

However, I'm having an issue getting it to work with two arrays. I want my RESideMenu to display a certain array of menu items if a user is logged in, and a different array of menu items if there is no user.

Let's say I open the app, and I'm not logged in, the correct menu will display if I open the menu. However, if I then login, the menu won't change if I open it again, it stays the same as if I weren't logged in. Now, if I open the app, and I'm not logged in, then I log in, and take the app out of multitasking, open it again, now the "logged in" menu displays!

Here is the code in my .h file for my menu view:

```
//
//  JSAMenuViewController.h
//  JSApp
//
//  Created by Jacob Klapper on 10/31/13.
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RESideMenu.h"

@interface JSAMenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, RESideMenuDelegate>

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;

@property NSArray *currentArray;

@property NSArray *inTitles;

@property NSArray *outTitles;

@end
```

And the .m:

```
//
//  JSAMenuViewController.m
//  JSApp
//
//  Created by Jacob Klapper on 10/31/13.
//
//

#import "JSAMenuViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+RESideMenu.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface JSAMenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation JSAMenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //height 54 * 5
    //y = (self.view.frame.size.height - 54 * 5) / 2.0f
    self.tableView = ({
        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - 490) / 2.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 490) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.opaque = NO;
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        tableView.bounces = NO;
        tableView.scrollsToTop = NO;
        tableView;
    });
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    self.inTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Login", @"Register", @"About Us", @"Who's Who", @"Request a Position", @"My Debates", @"Submit an Idea", @"Debates", @"Logout", nil];

    self.outTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Login", @"Register", @"About Us", @"Who's Who", nil];

    if([PFUser currentUser])
    {
        self.currentArray = self.inTitles;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    else
    {
        self.currentArray = self.outTitles;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    //self.sideMenu.openStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    //self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableView Delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewController;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:

            if([PFUser currentUser])
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Already Logged In" message:@"Proceeding to the login screen will log you out of your current session." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

                alert.tag = 2;
                [alert show];
            }
            /*
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
             */
            break;
        case 1:
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"register"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
            break;
        case 2:
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"about"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
            break;
        case 3:
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"who"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
            break;
        case 4:
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"request"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
            break;
        case 5:
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"my"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
            break;
        case 6:
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"submit"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
            break;
        case 7:
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"debates"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
            break;
        case 8:
            [PFUser logOut];
            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableView Datasource

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 54;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    return [self.currentArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    }

    /*
    NSArray *titles = @[@"Login", @"Register", @"About Us", @"Who's Who", @"Request a Position", @"My Debates", @"Submit an Idea", @"Debates", @"Logout"];
    NSArray *images = @[@"group-50white@2x.png", @"group-50white@2x.png", @"group-50white@2x.png", @"group-50white@2x.png", @"group-50white@2x.png", @"group-50white@2x.png", @"group-50white@2x.png", @"group-50white@2x.png", @"group-50white@2x.png"];
     */
    cell.textLabel.text = self.currentArray[indexPath.row];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:images[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark RESideMenu Delegate

- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu willShowMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController
{
    NSLog(@"willShowMenuViewController");
}

- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu didShowMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController
{
    NSLog(@"didShowMenuViewController");
}

- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu willHideMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController
{
    NSLog(@"willHideMenuViewController");
}

- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu didHideMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController
{
    NSLog(@"didHideMenuViewController");
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


    if(alertView.tag == 2)
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [PFUser logOut];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewController;

            navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"]];
            [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];

        }
    }


}

@end
```

Should I be doing something different in order to implement/use two arrays in my tableview menu?

Thanks!

Comment: "However, if I then login, the menu won't change if I open it again, it stays the same as if I weren't logged in" -- how and where do you log in? Do you do that in this same controller? You're choosing your array in viewDidLoad, which is called only once when the controller first loads. That could be the problem, but it's hard to tell without understanding the work flow of your app.

Comment: I log in on another view. I press a menu item, which brings me to the login view.

I think my problem is that I'm choosing it in viewDidLoad. I was unaware that was called only once, the first time the controller loads. What method should I be changing the array in, in order to make the menu items change if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I just solved my own problem haha. I was experimenting with putting the array-changing code in different methods, and this one worked:

```
- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu willShowMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController
{
    NSLog(@"willShowMenuViewController");

    self.inTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Login", @"Register", @"About Us", @"Who's Who", @"Request a Position", @"My Debates", @"Submit an Idea", @"Debates", @"Logout", nil];

    self.outTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Login", @"Register", @"About Us", @"Who's Who", nil];

    if([PFUser currentUser])
    {
        self.currentArray = self.inTitles;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    else
    {
        self.currentArray = self.outTitles;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

It is called every time the menu is going to appear.